# BinarySearchTree - Wrong Result Search Method

Tags: java, algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

If I search at BST for element for example 40, I get the value of the Node if it exists 39 or 41 otherwise I get the value from the correct node. I tried everything to fix it, but it still does not work. My Code:

```java
    @Override
    public void insert(int key, String string) {
        head = recursiveInsert(head,key,string);
    }

    public Node recursiveInsert(Node node, int key, String string) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            head = new SearchTree.Node(key,string);
        } else {
            if (head.key < key) {
                head.left = recursiveInsert(head.left, key,string);
            } else {
                head.right = recursiveInsert(head.right,key,string);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int key) {

    }

    @Override
    public String search(int key) {
        return recursiveSearch(head,key).value;
    }

    public Node recursiveSearch(SearchTree.Node node, int key){
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (head.key == key) {
            return head;
        } else {
            if (key < head.key){
                return recursiveSearch(head.left, key);
            }else return recursiveSearch(head.right,key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getCumulativeLengthOfSearchPaths() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `tried everything` hard to see. Present a variant including (execution and value) trace statements. Stare hard at the comparisons.

Comment: *for example 40, I get the value of the Node if it exists 39 or 41 otherwise I get the value from the correct node.* Can you elaborate on it? You have 40 in the BST but if it doesn't exist you get the nearby node and if it exists you get the node having it? that's what you meant?

Comment: Um, is the code presented "the good version"? How did you check the result of `insert()`? (What are the public declarations in/of `SearchTree`, including `Node`?)

Comment: Please create a [MCVE].